# Django admin crashes when adding or editing object

Tags: django

I have a django model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

With the admin registered as a model admin.

When I try to either edit an existing Foo object (which I first added directly to the DB with SQL) or click 'add' to create a new Foo object, the server crashes. Does this have something to do with the fact that the User table contains about 50,000 objects, and the server is running out of memory when it tries to load the Foo admin, because it OneToOne keys out to User?

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to make `user` a [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) field, so Django won't attempt to load those 50,000 User objects.

```py
class FooAdmin(...):
    # ...
    raw_id_fields = ('user',)
```

If you're using Django 2.0+, you can also use [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) instead.